# How to reclassify pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
> print(df)

           image_name                       tags
0                img1       class1 class2 class3
1                img2                     class2
2                img3              class2 class3
3                img4                     class1
```

How can I reclassify the `tags` column such that any row with a `class3` value gets assigned the string "yes" and everything else the string "no"?

I am aware that I can check for instances of a search word using the following:

```
df['tags'].str.contains('class3')
```

However, I am not sure how to integrate this into the task at hand.

The following is the intended output:

```
           image_name                       tags
0                img1                        yes
1                img2                         no
2                img3                        yes
3                img4                         no
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as:

```
df['tags'] = np.where(df['tags'].str.contains('class3'),'yes','no')
```

Or

```
df['tags'] = 'no'
df.loc[df['tags'].str.contains('class3'),'tags'] = 'yes'
```

Or

```
df['tags'] = ['yes' if 'class3' in s else 'no' for s in df3.tags.values]
```

---

The output for above methods:

```
print(df)
  image_name tags
0       img1  yes
1       img2   no
2       img3  yes
3       img4   no
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do:

```
df['tags'] = df.tags.str.contains('class3').map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})
>>> df
  image_name tags
0       img1  Yes
1       img2   No
2       img3  Yes
3       img4   No
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will a little bit faster than `str.contains`

```
v=np.array(['Yes','No'])[np.array(['class3' in x for x in df.tags]).astype(int)]
v
Out[267]: array(['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes'], dtype='<U3')
#df['tags']=v
```

Timing list below

```
#df=pd.concat([df]*1000)
#sacul
%timeit df.tags.str.contains('class3').map({True:'Yes',False:'No'})
The slowest run took 10.12 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100 loops, best of 3: 3.11 ms per loop
#Mine
%timeit np.array(['Yes','No'])[np.array(['class3' in x for x in df.tags]).astype(int)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 390 µs per loop
#Borealis
%timeit np.where(df['tags'].str.contains('class3'),'yes','no')
100 loops, best of 3: 2.46 ms per loop
```